# template croosdomain with requirejs returns blank page

Tags: javascript, requirejs, chaplinjs

I implementing one app html5 with chaplinjs (can see here https://github.com/andru255/chtw), the paths of the htmls runing good, but returning blank pages when release the request by firebug and showin in red like a error in request, but in other tab in the browser loads very well the path of this template, whats happen in this case? what fail in the request?

Comment: please show the code you are using

Comment: hi Patrick, thnks for the reply, no problem I submit the fix a the repo for all people what have the same problem or need a reference :).